# JS: I cannot manage my files and code rich text editor at the same time

Tags: javascript, text-editor, rich-text-editor, file-manager

I want to make a texte editor in javascript and I was managing the files very well : save and export and read my files that I have created.
I wanted to start the second phase that was to write my files using rich-text.
And the issue was that I used in my html  that don't accept my rich-text code.
So I have two features that are not compatibles.

This my code, it manages the file and the rich text isn't working:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #547793;
    }
    .one {
      background-color: #C1C9CC;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      margin-left: 4.5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #editor {
      background-color: #F7F2EF;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      width: 60%;
      height: 500px;
      float: right;
    }
    #sidebar {
      background-color: #E0E0E0;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      width: 20%;
      height: 500px;
      float: left;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    #sidebar ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 10;
    }
    #sidebar li:hover {
      background-color: #C1C9CC;
    }
    h1{
      color: #6CEEEF;
      font-family: "Palatino";
      font-size: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 4px 2px;
    }
    #toolbar {
      background-color: #E0E0E0;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      width: 60%;
      height: 50px;
      float: right;
    }

  </style>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-saver@2.0.2/dist/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>SYLLABLE</h1>
  <div id="toolbar">
    <button id="boldButton">Bold</button>
    <button id="italicButton">Italic</button>
    <button id="underlineButton">Underline</button>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul id="file-list"></ul>
  </div>
  <textarea id="editor"></textarea>

  <button class="one" id="save-btn">Save</button>
  <button class="one" id="export-btn">Export</button>


  <script>

    // Récupérez la liste des fichiers enregistrés à partir du localStorage
    var fileList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fileList")) || [];

    // Affichez la liste des fichiers dans la barre latérale
    var fileListEl = document.getElementById("file-list");
    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
      var file = fileList[i];
      var fileItem = document.createElement("li");
      fileItem.innerHTML = file.name;
      fileListEl.appendChild(fileItem);

      //efface le fichier avec dblclick
        fileItem.addEventListener("dblclick", (function(file) {
            return function() {
            var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
            editor.value = file.content;
            var index = fileList.indexOf(file);
            fileList.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("fileList", JSON.stringify(fileList));
            location.reload();
            };
        })(file));


      // Écoutez les événements de clic sur le fichier
      var previouslySelectedFileItems = [];

      fileItem.addEventListener("click", (function(file) {
        return function() {
          // Chargez le contenu du fichier dans l'éditeur de texte
          var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
          editor.value = file.content;

        // Reset the color of the previously selected file items to the default
        for (var i = 0; i < previouslySelectedFileItems.length; i++) {
        previouslySelectedFileItems[i].style.color = "blue";
         }

         // Change the color of the newly selected file item to red
        this.style.color = "red";

        // Keep track of the newly selected file item
        previouslySelectedFileItems.push(this);
        };

      })(file));
    }

    // Enregistrez un nouveau fichier
    var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
    saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
      var name = prompt("Enter file name: ");
      if (name) {
        var file = { name: name, content: editor.value };
        fileList.push(file);
        localStorage.setItem("fileList", JSON.stringify(fileList));

        // Ajoutez le fichier à la liste affichée
        var fileItem = document.createElement("li");
        fileItem.innerHTML = file.name;
        fileListEl.appendChild(fileItem);
        fileItem.style.color = "#389596";


        // Écoutez les événements de clic sur le fichier
        fileItem.addEventListener("click", (function(file) {
          return function() {
            // Chargez le contenu du fichier dans l'éditeur de texte
            var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
            editor.value = file.content;

          };
        })(file));
      }
    });

    // Exportez la liste des fichiers
    var exportBtn = document.getElementById("export-btn");
    var editor = document.getElementById("editor");

    exportBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var text = editor.value;
    var blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    var name = prompt("Enter file name: ");
    if (name) {
        var file = { name: name, content: editor.value };
        fileList.push(file);
      saveAs(blob, name);
    }});

    const boldButton = document.getElementById("boldButton");
      const italicButton = document.getElementById("italicButton");
      const underlineButton = document.getElementById("underlineButton");
      const textEditor = document.getElementById("editor");

      boldButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.execCommand("bold", false, null);
      });

      italicButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.execCommand("italic", false, null);
      });

      underlineButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.execCommand("underline", false, null);
      });


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't merged their functionality at all, they are both on different pages using different scripts. Can you show what happens when you implement the file upload functionality for the editor? Otherwise we would have to completely program that for you. Please don't use SO as a free coding service.

Comment: I have updated the question with your advice.

Comment: @karinev as per mdn document text area accepts only plain texts and its does not formatting. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand
.
you can try different way to achieve this.

Comment: Many other rich text editors are open source. You could take a look how they work using the browser console and their original source code.

Comment: @Kesavan R,
Unfortunately, the execCommand are deprecated.